# How to allow python script to access a root-owned docker container log file?

Tags: python, docker, root, sudo

I wrote a short python program (one script with ~100 lines) that basically tracks the log of a running docker container located in:
`/var/lib/docker/containers/7d847e/7d847e-json.log`, where `7d847e` is the container id.

However, the path `/var/lib/docker/containers/` is owned by root. I `tail` the log file in command line with `sudo tail -f ...`, but how can I make the python script access the file?

I can think of the following ways:

1. change the owner of `/var/lib/docker/containers/` to me; (not sure if this breaks other stuff)
2. save the sudo password somewhere and allow the python script to access it

They both look like bad idea to me.
What is the best practice?

Comment: You could run your script in a container as root bind-mounting `/var/lib/docker/containers` i.e. (in your workspace): `docker run --rm -it -v /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers -v ${PWD}:/workspace/source -w /workspace/source --entrypoint python3 python:3.7-slim-buster myapp.py`. All the things in `docker` \o/

Comment: Run the script itself under sudo, `sudo ./my_script.py`.  @masseyb's suggestion is just another way to run the script with root permissions.

Comment: All Roads Lead to Rome. I <3 `docker`.